# Web service is available in device browser, but not in app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am currently working on a Xamarin Forms application and I am attempting to call a REST API that is running locally from a physical android device. I am able to browse to the url

http://localhost:3000/api/orders_initial/0333a05b-5c49-48d6-8e60-1eb6a4d627ff

in Opera/Chrome on the device and get the expected JSON result. I am also able to successfully call the REST API from some REST API Client apps available in the Play Store. However, when I try to call the REST API from my app, I am getting a connection refused error. Any ideas why this might be? The following is the code used to call the REST API:

```
private string baseUrl = @"http://localhost:3000/api/";
    private HttpClient client;

    public RestService() {
        client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }

    public async Task<List<Order>> GetOrdersForInitialSync(Guid id) {
        var uri = new Uri(baseUrl + @"orders_initial/" + id.ToString());
        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Order>>(content);
        }
        else {
            return new List<Order>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use localhost, use the IP or FQDN of your server.  Also be sure that your app has the necessary permissions set in the manifest.

Comment: Using the IP doesn't work. localhost worked fine in the browser and REST API Client apps I downloaded from the Play Store. Do you know what the proper permissions are? I have the INTERNET permission set. Are there any others?

Comment: localhost should loopback to the device/emulator your code is running on, not the server hosting your service.  Even if the emulator is running on the same machine as the service, they should have different IPs assigned.

Comment: The use of localhost is clearly not the issue. If it were, then the URL in my question would not work in the device's browser and other apps on the device. My adb is configured to reverse forward localhost:3000 to my desktop.

Comment: OK, that's good to know.  99.9% of the connectivity issues posted here for mobile services have to do with not understanding how localhost works on a mobile device.  You probably need to break out a packet sniffer and compare the request from your app to one from a test client to see what the difference is.

Comment: CORS issue perhaps? What's the security set up on your API like?